# Trouble running modelsim on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 and I downloaded Altera Modelsim from this site [Install Modelsim in Ubuntu](http://vineeshvs.blogspot.in/2014/02/installing-and-using-modelsim-in-ubuntu.html)

I followed all the instructions but the `./vsim` command doesnt seem to be working. I'm new to Ubuntu and so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Please help!!

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" doesn't give us much to go on: what happens, exactly? are there any error messages? is your system 32-bit or 64-bit? if the latter, did you follow the linked additional instructions for installing 32-bit libraries?

Comment: I'm working on an 64 bit ubuntu. I'm getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error when i run the vsim command.

Comment: ** Fatal: Read failure in vlm process (0,0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I tried the process in this [link](http://mattaw.blogspot.in/2014/05/making-modelsim-altera-starter-edition.html) but I'm unable to build libfreetype6 dependencies.

Comment: Picking 'freetype' as source package instead of 'libfreetype6'
E: Unable to find a source package for freetype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. The instructions cited below work perfectly. Download VIM editor (available in Software Center) before following the given solution.

> ## Making ModelSim ALTERA STARTER EDITION vsim 10.1d work on Ubuntu 14.04
>
> [WARNING: Some people are reporting that following the steps for them does not fix the problem. I am working on trying to find out what the issue is.]
>
> Trying to get a version of ModelSim running on a very modern version of Linux often presents challenges. Luckily I had lots of helpful information on the internet (major sources linked below) to get it going. This article mostly adapts the work done by the Arch Linux crew.
>
> **Problem number one:** The free version of ModelSim Altera Edition is 32 bit only while the normal Linux PC will be 64 bit.
>
> On Linux this requires us to install the 32 bit versions of the libraries that it depends on. Luckily this is fully supported on a modern Linux like Ubuntu 14.
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>
> sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib \
> lib32z1 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 \
> expat:i386 fontconfig:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libexpat1:i386 libc6:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 \
> libcanberra0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libice6:i386 libsm6:i386 libncurses5:i386 zlib1g:i386 \
> libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxft2:i386 libxrender1:i386 \
> libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386
> ```
>
> **Problem number two:** If you have the following error when running vsim:
>
> ```
> ** Fatal: Read failure in vlm process (0,0)
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```
>
> Then you probably need to build a new version of freetype, a font setting library and modify ModelSim to use it. For an unknown reason ModelSim has an issue with modern versions shipping in Arch and Ubuntu 14.04. First download the source code of freetype 2.4.12:
>
> http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.4.12.tar.bz2
>
> Now install the build dependencies needed for libfreetype6, extract the source (using tar) and configure and build libfreetype:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get build-dep -a i386 libfreetype6
>
> tar -xjvf freetype-2.4.12.tar.bz2
> cd freetype-2.4.12
> ./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
> make -j8
> ```
>
> The finished libraries are now available inside the `objs/.libs` directory. As they are necessary to run ModelSim we need to copy them into the install directory so they don't get lost and then modify ModelSim's vsim script to use the new libraries instead of the system wide versions. Change directory to the directory where you installed ModelSim, `/opt/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/`, on my system. Note you may need to edit the directory paths to match those used on your system.
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir lib32
> sudo cp ~/Downloads/freetype-2.4.12/objs/.libs/libfreetype.so* ./lib32
> ```
>
> Now we need to edit the vsim launch script to ensure the new freetype libraries are used:
>
> ```
> sudo vim bin/vsim
> ```
>
> Search for the following line:
>
> ```
> dir=`dirname $arg0`
> ```
>
> and underneath add the following new line:
>
> ```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${dir}/lib32
> ```
>
> Test by running vsim and hopefully you will be greeted by the ModelSim GUI.
>
> [Tested on fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04]

<sup>([Source](http://mattaw.blogspot.in/2014/05/making-modelsim-altera-starter-edition.html))</sup>

Comment: If editing the vco file doesn't work, run vsim as follows: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/lib32 ./vsim`